# Abrir un archivo con Java desde un servidor que requiere autenticacion

Tags: java

Buenas, estoy intentando realizar un aplicación en java, en la que el programa pide el nombre del documento (en mi caso un pdf) y se busca dentro de una carpeta compartida remotamente, en caso de que exista, abre el documento pdf. Esto lo estoy realizando actualmente de la siguiente manera:

```
String NomFichero = "file://200.10.10.156/Carpeta/archivo";
if(java.awt.Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
   try {
      Desktop dk = Desktop.getDesktop();
      dk.browse(new URI(NomFichero+".pdf"));
   }
   catch(Exception e1) {
      try {
         Desktop dk = Desktop.getDesktop();
         dk.browse(new URI(NomFichero+".jpg"));
      }
      catch(Exception e2) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ERROR: "+ e2.getMessage());
      }          
   }    
}
```

Esto me funciona perfectamente si yo ingreso primeramente de PC a PC, y reconozco la credencial para el equipo cliente. Pero la idea es acceder ya con la autenticación para evitar dicho paso.

Se de una libreria jcifs, viene a ser una implementación de samba, en donde si podemos ingresar a carpetas compartidas remotamente, y con las credenciales en cuestión, es más, utilizo esta librería para el acceso a la carpeta en el momento de editar el nombre de un documento o bien eliminarlo, pero para abrirlo francamente no encuentro un método que pueda utilizar.
Agredecería mucho de su ayuda. Exitos!

Comment: Es un servidor FTP?

Comment: Si, es un servidor ftp

Comment: Es más, intente conectarme a través de la clase FTPClient, de la librería apache.commons.ftp, y nada, ahí ni realiza la conexión. Mediante este método por lo menos ingresa a la carpeta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leo en los comentarios que se trata de un ***servidor FTP***, por lo que deberías utilizar la mencionada librería de *Apache*, en concreto haciendo uso de la clase [*FTPClient*](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html).

La solución que propongo es para **atacar un equipo** *Windows* que aloje una **carpeta compartida** (o en su defecto, un servidor *SAMBA*), previa autenticación usando la librería [*JCIFS*](https://jcifs.samba.org/).

Ten en cuenta que, al menos en el ejemplo que propones, la dirección *IP* del ordenador **es pública** (habrá que hacer *NAT* si no está dentro de la misma subred).

Solución:

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import jcifs.UniAddress;
import jcifs.smb.NtlmPasswordAuthentication;
import jcifs.smb.SmbException;
import jcifs.smb.SmbSession;

public class Pruebas {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Autenticación
        try {
            NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(
                "WORKGROUP;Usuario:Password"
            );
            UniAddress dc = UniAddress.getByName("200.10.10.156");
            SmbSession.logon(dc, auth);
        } catch (SmbException | UnknownHostException ex) {
        }

        // Tu código
        String NomFichero = "file://200.10.10.156/Carpeta/archivo";
        if (java.awt.Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
            try {
                Desktop dk = Desktop.getDesktop();
                dk.browse(new URI(NomFichero + ".pdf"));
            } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e1) {
                try {
                    Desktop dk = Desktop.getDesktop();
                    dk.browse(new URI(NomFichero + ".jpg"));
                } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e2) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR: " + e2.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por el interés y tu tiempo, mira, en esta línea me salta al catch: UniAddress dc = UniAddress.getByName("smb://200.10.10.156/Carpeta/"); Tienes idea del porque puede ser? Ya que el getMessage() no me dice mucho, me sale esto: smb://200.10.10.156/Carpeta/

Comment: Corrección: UniAddress dc = UniAddress.getByName("200.10.10.156"); Este método debe recibir solamente la dirección IP de la PC a la cuál voy a solicitar los datos. De todas maneras, muchísimas gracias por guiarme

Comment: Hola Carlos, acabo de cambiarlo. Si te sirvió, ¿podrías marcarla como válida? En caso contrario, puedo seguir ayudando si es preciso.

Comment: De lujo amigo, ahora si funcionó. Muchas gracias!